# How to filter and all the categories in a single statement using django

Tags: django

I have prog, associateprof, assistantprof, research scholar and mtech categories and to get count of those I am using each statement for each. Instead is there any chance to know in a single statement or using for loop.
I am doing like this :

```
  count= Snippet.objects.all().count()
    count1 = Snippet.objects.filter(designation = 'Prof').count()
    count2 = Snippet.objects.filter(designation = 'RA').count()
    count3 = Snippet.objects.filter(designation = 'MTech').count()
    count4 = Snippet.objects.filter(designation = 'Asstprof').count()
    count5 = Snippet.objects.filter(designation = 'Assocprof').count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **GROUP BY** clause as ,

```
from django.db.models import Count

Snippet.objects.values('designation').annotate(count=Count('designation')).order_by('designation')
```